# search substring from mutable array in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar

How to search substring from NSMutableArray?

NSMutableArray **names** having string values,

searchText is a substring to search from name array values.

```
for (NSString *sTemp in names)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        //NSLog(@"sTemp = %@, searchText = %@",sTemp,searchText);
        NSLog(@"%@",titleResultsRange.length);
        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [Items addObject:sTemp];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it right. What is the problem?
You can also do it like:

```
for (NSString *sTemp in names)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (titleResultsRange.location != NSNotFound)
            [Items addObject:sTemp];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But its not taking values from sTemp into Items array. It shows null when I try to fetch the Items array values into Console. what can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You also could filter your array with a NSPredicate, like this:

```
NSArray *items = [names filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[cd] %@",searchText]];
```